# Data Protection Error when Running Build on Client System

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, data-protection, build-agent

-Using TFS 2015 Update 3 On Premise Server
-Build Agent is installed on a user's Windows 7 PC

After creation of the Build Agent, builds run successfully for 12-24 hours.

After that, receives the following error:
"The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating."

Since this is running on user's box, not the server, all Google points to the Load User Profile setting in IIS is not valid, I believe.

This has not occurred on any builds using Build Agents on the TFS server.

Comment: What kind of project do you run? In which build step when the error occurred?

Comment: It seems to be erroring out within a locally coded step. I'm reading through that script now to see what things it is looking out for that might be failing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Windows System Pre-requisites](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/start/envwin.md) of Deploy an agent on Windows, you need to use one of the windows below:

- Windows 10 and Beyond (64-bit)
- Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 (64-bit)
  [Updated C runtime is needed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226)

Make sure your environment meets the requirement. Also, check your TFS application pool to see whether the user profile is loaded.

[image]